# Why won't my MenuBar show?

Tags: java, codenameone, mobile-application

I have a simple test case with two forms and a side menu. When I show the first form, the side menu is missing. After I go to the wizard form and come back, the side menu shows up as it should. But I can't get the side menu to show up when the application is first launched.

I should note that the Developer's Guide has nothing on the MenuBar component. If there's another way I should be using it, the MenuBar javadocs should say so.

```
import com.codename1.ui.*;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BoxLayout;
import com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager;

public class Playground {

  private Form current;
  private MainForm mainForm;
  public void init(Object context) {
    UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");
    Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true); // Didn't help.
    mainForm = new MainForm();
  }

  public void start() {
    if (current != null) {
      current.show();
      return;
    }

    Form hi = mainForm;
    hi.show();
    current = hi;
  }

  public void stop() {
  }

  public void destroy() {
  }

  private class MainForm extends Form {
    MainForm() {
      super("Test of Hamburger Menu");
      setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
      Button spacer = new Button("Wizard");
      spacer.addActionListener((evt)-> showWizard());
      add(spacer);
      Label normalLabel = new Label("Normal text");
      add(normalLabel);

      Toolbar toolbar = new Toolbar();
      setToolbar(toolbar); // I apparently need to do this or set GlobalToolbar to true, or the menu icon won't appear at all.
//      MenuBar menubar = toolbar.getMenuBar(); // Didn't help.
      MenuBar menubar = getMenuBar();
      Command dummyOne = new Command("One");
      Command dummyTwo = new Command("Two");
      menubar.addCommand(dummyOne);
      menubar.addCommand(dummyTwo);
    }
  }

  private void showWizard() {
    Form wizardForm = new Form("Wizard");
    wizardForm.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    Button done = new Button("Done");
    done.addActionListener((evt)-> backToMain());
    wizardForm.add(done);
    wizardForm.show();
  }

  private void backToMain() {
    mainForm.show();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Toolbar to add your Commands.

```
toolbar.addCommandToSideMenu(dummyOne);
```

Comment: Okay. Thank you. Let me just say that the javadocs for the MenuBar class should say this. If I'm not supposed to invoke the constructor, I need the javadocs to be clear about that. A "see also," which takes me to the Toolbar method, would also be helpful.

Comment: The Toolbar is a relatively new API compared to the MenuBar class, if you use the Toolbar all commands should be managed/controlled by the Toolbar. There are still some use cases where the MenuBar makes sense and can be used.